# VBA Word Email zipped pdf file folder

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I want to send pdf files from within a MS Word docm file. This file is linked with an Excel source file to perform Mail Merge function. With the support of http://word.officeacademy.it/450/word-come-fare-stampa-unione-direttamente-in-singoli-file-pdf-vba/ and http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win001.htm I started to create a Macro:

```
Sub NewZip(sPath)
'Create empty Zip File
'Changed by keepITcool Dec-12-2005
    If Len(Dir(sPath)) > 0 Then Kill sPath
    Open sPath For Output As #1
    Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
    Close #1
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Unione_in_pdf()

Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim file As Variant

'Crea un oggetto FileDialog per scegliere la cartella in cui salvare i file
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fd

    'Usa il metodo Show per mostrare la finestra di dialogo e restituire l'azione dell'utente
    If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems

            'vrtSelectedItem è una stringa che contiene l'indirizzo di ogni elemento selezionato.
            'E' possibile usare qualsiasi funzione di I/O sui file utilizzando questo indirizzo.
            SelectedPath = vrtSelectedItem

            Next vrtSelectedItem

    Else
            MsgBox ("Nessuna cartella è stata selezionata.")
            Exit Sub
    End If

End With

'Imposta la variabile oggetto a Nothing
Set fd = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

MainDoc = ActiveDocument.Name
ChangeFileOpenDirectory SelectedPath
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount
    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
        .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = i
            .LastRecord = i
            .ActiveRecord = i

            'Utilizza alcuni campi del file sorgente per impostare il nome del file pdf
            'IMPORTANTE: tali campi vanno personalizzati in base a quelli effettivamente
            'presenti nella sorgente dati
            docName = "Lettera_" & .DataFields("NomeCentro").Value & "_" & .DataFields("Allievo").Value & ".pdf"
            Value = .DataFields("NomeCentro").Value
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    End With

    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=docName, _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Folder = ActiveDocument.Path
    DestFolder = Folder & Application.PathSeparator & Value
    If Len(Dir(DestFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then

        MkDir DestFolder

        Dim FileNameZip
        Dim oApp As Object

            If Right(DestFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
                DestFolder = DestFolder & "\"
            End If

        FileNameZip = DestFolder & "MyZip" & ".zip"

        'Create empty Zip File
        NewZip (FileNameZip)

        Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        'Copy the files to the compressed folder
        oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(DestFolder).items

        'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done
        On Error Resume Next
        Do Until oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).items.Count = _
           oApp.Namespace(DestFolder).items.Count
            Application.OnTime When:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), _
  Name:="MyDelayMacro"
        Loop
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Create the mail
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                  "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
                  "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
                  "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
                  "This is line 4"

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
            .Body = strbody
            .Attachments.Add FileNameZip
            .Send   'or use .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0         

        End If

Next i

       Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I create pdf files, create folders but I can't zip files in created folders.

I need to find all the files with the keyword in the Dim Value ("NomeCentro" field in the Excel source file) and the zip and copy in the "NomeCentro" folder previously created.

Finally I need to send a mail for each zip file (I've not tested the mail code cause debug stops me before).

Edit: the error generates a popup with (try to translate message) "Cannot Move a Compressed (zipped) Folder into itself" at the line

```
oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(DestFolder).items
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you get any error messages? If yes, can you pls provide them here and indicate in which line you receive them?

Edit: Based on the error message provided below in comment, the problem is that the zip file is located in the path indicated by DestFolder and then you try to copy all items within DestFolder to the zip file, but all items include the zip file itself.

Create the zip file in a path that will not be affected by the copy call.

Comment: the error generate a popup with (try to translate messagge) "Cannot Move a Compressed (zipped) Folder into itself" al the line

`oApp.Namespace(FileNameZip).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(DestFolder).items`